# angular-bootstrap-ui full-width table or list inside accordion

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working with angularjs and the angular-bootstrap-ui package. Specifically, I am using bootstrap list-groups within the body of an accordion-group. I would like the list-group-items to extend all the way to the containing accordion-group's border. Here is a fiddle of the fragment, http://jsfiddle.net/qwesmv1d/1/. The list-group-items are being displayed with padding; however, I would like it to be 'full-width' as in this example, http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-list-group.

Code snippet ...

    `<accordion>
      <accordion-group heading="Subject">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
        </ul>
      </accordion-group>
    </accordion>`

Any help appreciated .. thanks.

Comment: You will need to show some code of what you have tried already otherwise we have no idea what to suggest to you.

Comment: `I am having trouble` is not an adequate problem statement

Answer (score 1):

Override panel-body padding:
Add this into your main css

```
.panel-body{
    padding : 0px;
}
```

Comment: This just removes the padding. There are still duplicate borders and they aren't rounded correctly. It should look like: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-list-group